# (neo)vim/emacs support of source decorations (meta source code info)?

Tags: vim, emacs, neovim

This is a dump non-vim, non-emacs user question to the users of those editors.

VScode supports such things as decorations of the code:

- color highlight the text ranges
- or insert some helper text content that actually does not belong to the source content but is visible for the user.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/decorator-sample/README.md

Do 1) vim, 2) neovim, 3) emacs support this kind of editor extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all three support something to that effect.

For vim, a way to do something similar to the example is to use the `:syntax` command.

[image: screenshot]

To approximate the example (small numbers one color, big numbers another), you could say:

```
:syntax match Identifier "\<[0-9]\{,2}\>"
:syntax match Error "\<[0-9]\{3,}\>"
```

Or, in prose: highlight numbers up to 2 digits as identifiers, and numbers of 3 digits or more as errors. The exact colors depend on your `colorscheme`.

This is not an extension/plugin in the VSCode sense - although you could write a vim plugin or syntax file that does this if you want. It's the same machinery that gets used for vim's built-in syntax highlighting. (That also means that if you're looking at a file that's already highlighted, it may not show up.)

The amount of interesting graphical things you can do will vary based on whether you're running vim inside a terminal or not.

Documentation: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html

Comment: Thanks, and is it possible to insert meta text content in a certain position?